# How do I update the data label of a chart?

Tags: excel

For example, I have a pie chart, 95% of it is blue.

Now I update some excel fields that have to do with the blue area of the piechart, 95% then goes down to 90%.

Now I want to also update the Data label of the blue area because it is still 95% and not 90%, instead of changing it manually, how can I make excel update the labels for me?

Comment: If the chart is actually using the value which *changed* (from 95 to 90), then the label should reflect that change automatically. There are some exceptions to this maybe, but without being able to see/know how your data and chart are configured, it's tough to speculate on why your chart isn't behaving the "normal" way.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks David, you helped me find the problem, I put text with the label, example: "Blue occupies 95%", can you put text? Or is this not allowed/ will never work?

Comment: There's a way to make data labels linked to cell via formula, hold on I will try to make an example for you with some screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to build the labels via formula somewhere on a worksheet. Once you've done that, you can link the chart's labels to the cell containing the "data labels"

To build your data labels, somewhere else on your worksheet (conveniently, in the adjacent column would be ideal), use Excel formula to build the desired label string, for example: `="Blue occupies "&TEXT(B3,"0%")`

[image]

Repeat for the other points in the chart.

Once you've done that, here's how you link Data Labels to a cell reference (normally, Data Labels are linked to the underlying data *value*).

1. *Select* the data label
2. Then, place your cursor in Excel's *Formula Bar*, and enter the formula like `='Sheet2'!$C$3`.

Now, that data label is associated by the formula, to the cell C3, which contains the desired data label that we built above.  Repeat as needed.

[image]

**Note:** The sheet name is required in this formula. Use single-quotes around the sheet name if it contains spaces.